# Excel ListBox Weird Behaviour

Tags: excel, listbox

Ok, there is something going on here that I can not find a solution to it. I have 2 list box loaded in a form, ListBox1, and listBox2. ListBox1 is loading the files names from a specific folder while ListBox2 loads specific information from this files as you click on each one.

The way I did it was, when you click the file on the left side, the file is opened, a specific data range is copied into memory, dumped into ListBox2 and, the file is closed after.

All this works but there is a problem. The copy/paste operation into ListBox2 works fine (characters are copied exactly from the source), when I leave the excel workbook opened but when I tried to copy/paste and close the source excel file I get very strange characters in ListBox2. see below. I know the ListBox has a limitation of 32k items but this is not the case, the range copied is 200 rows.

This behavior happens when I close the excel in the background with

Workbooks(workbooknow).Close SaveChanges:=False

If I comment out the above code. The listbox2 shows beautifully. I don't understand why the difference with the file opened or not since the data is already dumped into ListBox2 before I close the file. Is this a memory issue???

Answer (score 1):

ok, this was an easy fix, I loaded the data from an array , all is perfect now

```
Dim DataArray As Variant
```

AND THEN.....

DataArray = Range("A9:F200").Value

```
With Me.ListBox2
         .List = DataArray
         .ColumnHeads = False
         .ColumnWidths = "70;70;50;100;260;80"
         .ColumnCount = 6
         .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
End With
```